# Wix + InstallDirdlg + character limits in pathEdit

Tags: wix

I am working on a Windows installer, in **InstallDirdlg** dialog I want to limit the number of characters entered in the pathEdit control.

Is there any way to edit this **pathEdit** control and set the limit to some specified number?
Do I have to overwrite the whole InstallDirdlg?

Answer (score 4):

You can start with a copy of the InstallDirDlg and edit it to suit your needs fairly easility:

[Customizing Wix dialogs](http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/)

To limit the PathEdit control you place the max number of characters in curly braces in the Text attribute. For example for max length of 80 this should work (note: I removed all the other control attributes for brevity)

```
<Control Type="PathEdit" Property="MYPROP" Text="{80}" />
```

[MSDN docs on PathEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370749%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)